# Em D3.geo, como obter os dados de uma projeção?

Tags: javascript, array, d3.js

Estou utilizando somente o D3.geo, não a biblioteca completa D3, mas tão somente o D3.geo.

Configuro a projeção e carrego os dados GeoJSON MultiPolygon.

Eu eté consigo o retorno dos dados da seguinte forma

```
projectionVale = d3.geo.stereographic()
.rotate(rotation)
.translate([width/2, height/2])
.scale([scale])
.clipAngle(90);

mapVale = d3.geo.path().projection(projectionVale);
path = mapVale(datajson);
```

Dessa forma ele retorna os caminhos já otimizados e prontos(o que é a intenção do D3 óbviamente) para plotar em SVG.

Como eu retorno somente os dados x,y desse polígono dessa projeção preferivelmente numa array?

Pois não tenho intenção de usar a biblioteca do D3 para plotar os dados em canvas ou SVG, somente o D3.geo mesmo, pois preciso somente dos dados para que eu possa ter a liberdade de fazer outro processamento nesses dados e de gerar o gráfico na tela da forma que preciso.

Answer (score 0):

Como eu estava precisando muito, decidi utilizar uma solução não ideal mas funcional.

No D3.geo existe uma método chamado d3_geo_pathBuffer(), que contém o conteúdo da projeção para retorno. Simplesmente alterei a forma de retorno para a forma que precisava.

No momento não é a solução ideal e limpa, mas é funcional para o uso necessário.